# Is it possible to get attachment content - Outlook Add-in API

Tags: outlook-addin

Is it possible to get attachment content(eml file) in Outlook Add-in API?. If yes, please guide how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Attachment.SaveAsFile` to save the attachment.

If you are trying to access the attachment contents without saving the attachment as a file, Outlook Object Model won't help you. You can use either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and open the attachment data as a stream (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream, ...)`) or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - its attachment objects expose `AsText`, `AsArray`, etc properties.

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  for each attach in item.Attachments
    MsgBox attach.AsText
  next
```

Comment: I would like to display the content of Attachment within the add-in that i have designed.

Comment: So what is the problem? Reading the file attachment data into a variable?

Comment: yes. Is it possible to do that? (file is in txt format)

Comment: You can save the attachment as a file using Attachment.SaveAsFile and then read the fiel contents. Are you trying to  read the attachment contents without saving the file first?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to read the attachment contents without saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on how to do this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh290849.aspx):

Using:

```
var attachmentData =
                attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN);
```

But when I tried to do this I just got an exception.

Comment: It will fail for large (16kB or so) attachments.